pyppeteer transform html into pdf, python
I have the code below that transforms an html string into a pdf, the problem is when loading the css fonts (which are within the html code), the script cannot load the fonts when generating the pdf, I didn't find anything when reading the documentation , pyppeteer can't read css?
the sources folder is in the same directory as my app.py file


import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch



async def generate_pdf(html_content, pdf_path):
    browser = await launch(executablePath="C:/Users/GUILHERME/Documents/chrome-win/chrome-win/chrome.exe") 
    page = await browser.newPage()
    
    await page.setContent(html_content)
    
    await page.pdf({'path': pdf_path, 'format': 'A4'})
    
    await browser.close()

async def main():
    html = """
        <html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IBPJ</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description">
    <meta name="author">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <style>

        h3#SAC {
            font-family: "Santander Text W05 Bold" !important;
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Santander Text W05 Regular";
            src: url(WebFonts/Santander/Santander.otf);
            src: url(WebFonts/Santander/Santander.otf) format("otf"),url(WebFonts/Santander/Santander.woff2) format("woff2"),url(WebFonts/Santander/Santander.woff) format("woff"),url(WebFonts/Santander/Santander.tff) format("truetype")
        }
</style>
</head>

<body class="print" style="display: block;">
    <div class="container-fluid print ">

        <div class="ng-star-inserted">
            <div class="ng-star-inserted">
                <div class="ng-star-inserted"><ibe-billets-receipts>
                        <div>
                            <div class="ng-star-inserted">
                                <div class="print-container" style="margin-bottom: -70;">
                                    <div
                                        class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pb-3 ng-star-inserted">
                                        <div class="col-6" style="margin-top: 10px;"><img width="160"
                                                alt="santander-logo"
                                                src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE">
                                        </div>
                                                </div><!----><!---->
                                                <div class="row space-t">
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -20;"><label
                                                                class="col-6">xxxx</label><label
                                                                class="col-3 font-weight-bold">R$&nbsp;xxxx</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><br>
                                                <div class="row space-t">
                                                    <div class="col-1">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="space-t space-l"><span
                                                                    class="alert-icon std-ic_circle_attention_fill space-r align-self-center"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-11">
                                                        
                                                </div>
                                                <hr>
                                                <div class="row space-t">
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <p class="text-right" style="font-size: 10px !important;"> xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <div class="bold" style="font-size: 10px !important;">xxxx
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row space-t">
                                                    <div class="col-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                                        <p class="text-right" style="font-size: 10px !important;">
                                                            xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <div class="bold" style="font-size: 10px !important;">
                                                            xxxx</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><!---->
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!---->
                                        <div class="row space-t" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                            <div class="col-5 text-left"><button id="returnDetailBtn" type="button"
                                                    ripple="" class="btn btn-secondary">xxxx</button></div>
                                            <div class="col-7 text-right">
                                                <div class="ibe-toolbar">
                                                    <div><span name="print" dssicon="" class="dss-icon-print"
                                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                                            role="presentation"></span><a>xxxx</a></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ibe-toolbar">
                                                    <div><span name="email" dssicon="" class="dss-icon-email"
                                                            aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"></span><a>xxxx</a></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div><ibe-toolbar-component>
                                                        <div class="ibe-toolbar"><!----><!----><!----><!----></div>
                                                        <ibe-dialog
                                                            class="text-left hide-print email-dialog ng-tns-c27-10 ng-star-inserted"><!----><!----></ibe-dialog>
                                                    </ibe-toolbar-component></div>
                                                <div class="ibe-toolbar">
                                                    <div><span name="document-pdf" dssicon=""
                                                            class="dss-icon-document-pdf" aria-hidden="true"
                                                            role="presentation"></span><a>xxxx</a></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ng-star-inserted" style="margin-left: 40px;">
                                            <hr><ibe-comprovante-component>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <h3 class="bold-head"
                                                            style="font-weight: bold !important; font-size: 20px !important;" id="SAC">
                                                           xxxx</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6 atendimento">
                                                        <h3 class="bold-head float-left"
                                                            style="font-weight: bold !important; font-size: 20px !important;" id="SAC">
                                                            SAC
                                                        </h3><span class="align-baseline"
                                                            style="line-height: 42px; font-size: 10px !important;">-
                                                            xxxx</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <p style="font-size: 10px !important; margin-top: -10px;">xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                                                        <p style="font-size: 10px !important; ">xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <p style="font-size: 10px !important; margin-top: -30px;">xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6" >
                                                        <p style="font-size: 10px !important; ">xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <p style="font-size: 10px !important; margin-top: -35px;">xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6 atendimento">
                                                        <h3 class="bold-head float-left"
                                                            style="font-size:18px !important; font-weight: bold;" id="SAC">
                                                            Ouvidoria</h3>
                                                        <span class="align-baseline"
                                                            style="line-height: 42px; font-size: 15px !important; font-size: 10px !important;">-
                                                            xxxx</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-6"> &nbsp; </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <p style="font-size: 10px !important;">xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-6"> &nbsp; </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <p style="font-size: 10px !important; margin-top: -15px;">xxxx</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </ibe-comprovante-component>
                                        </div><!----><!---->
                                    </div>
                    </ibe-billets-receipts></div><!---->
            </div>
            
        </div><!---->
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-print d-print-none" onclick="printContent()">Imprimir</button>

</body>

</html>
    """
    
    await generate_pdf(html, 'teste.pdf')

asyncio.run(main())



I didn't put my entire code here because it's too long, but the part that matters is my @font-face
If I run ONLY THE HTML SCRIPT, the font is recognized, but within my python code the fonts are not recognized
